# Option to contact moderators

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, account-suspension

Due to some "recent issues", I think the following is necessary:

Users need a way to contact moderators *through the StackOverflow website*.

This is especially important for suspensions, where there is no way to appeal or discuss the suspension from within SO itself.

Basically, there would be some kind of a box on the user's page that allows them to mention something to the moderators and some way to read the replies. (Or they could just go to the user's email.)

Comment: Something tells me that if a moderator suspended you ... they really don't want to talk to you.

Comment: Too bad. If someone has enough of a reason to do it, they owe the user an explanation.

Comment: But what if they are innocent?

Comment: I think we *do* owe a user at least an attempt at an explanation if we suspend them.  Usually we give that in advance, in the form of several warnings.  Suspensions aren't simple punishment, they're meant to discourage bad behavior.  You need to know what that behavior was before you can correct it.  If you don't know why you were suspended, you can contact us by emailing the team, as Jeff mentioned in his answer.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: You are enjoying the monopoly....

Comment: Since the moderator messaging system already gives users a way to reply to their suspension, I'm marking this [status-completed].

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you need to contact moderators through the website, there is already a way: flag something for moderator attention.

Beyond that, just use the "contact us" link provided at the bottom of every page.

Comment: I didn't know you could flag when you were suspended...

Comment: @George You only need 15 rep to flag as offensive, I believe all the other options are open.

Comment: @cha: Does that mean you can flag as spam with less than 15 rep? :P

Comment: Notably behavior like something getting deleted doesn't give you a means to flag that action for moderator attention, and there is no longer an email address at the bottom of every page - nor is there a way to contact moderators from their profile. Hole in the functionality of the site?

Comment: So seriously there is no way to contact moderators privately if the matter in question cannot be flagged? I don't see any email address provided at the bottom of every page, apart from the contact us link that seems to be a bit too broad.

Comment: So is there now a way to contact moderators? I have got 3 downvotes on different answers, because i downvoted an answer of another user (my first downvote), and i left a comment to tell him what i did not like. He also told, that he downvoted and that he will remove, but he did not. Of course i could flag that, but 3 downvotes are not worth a flag right? So what is the best i can do now?

Comment: If something isn't even worth raising a flag, then you should probably not waste any more thought on it, @Springrbua.

Comment: @Shog9 well i have now decided to flag it. Flagging on SO is different then flagging on other websites (most time there the users get kicked or something).