# How can I contact a moderator in a private setting?

Tags: support, moderators, private-messaging

Where can I seek help if I need assistance with contributor-related questions? For the purposes of this question, "contributor" means "user who provides more answers than questions." I.e. how can I contact a moderator in a private setting?

Comment: Just curious, what does "contributor" refer to?

Comment: @BoltClock One who *contributes* posts to an SE site I suppose?  Definitely unconventional word-choice =)

Comment: Why do you need to ask questions about people who happen to help more than they ask?

Comment: You're the one who asked the question, which is rather vague as is

Comment: You can always contact moderators privately via chat, using your moderator flags (on any post, including one of our own, just use the "other" field), or by emailing the team at the address given in the footer on every page. But most of these should be reserved only for really rare cases. Most questions can just be asked here on Meta. Anyone who can answer, will. The developers and moderators are very active participants, as are other users that are very familiar with the site/community and eager to help.

Comment: For the record, despite finding your question vague, I am not one who downvoted. Even given our exchange of comments.

Comment: Spencer: Downvotes are different on Meta: Check the [FAQ#vote-differences]. Don't take them personally. It could very well be that, as Adam Davis said, "Stack Exchange, Inc doesn't encourage one-on-one conversations with the moderators because they are busy enough already"

Comment: I suspect OP is upset about [the comments on this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9403162/397952)

Comment: @SpencerRuport I suspect it was a recalc.  I think one got run manually recently.

Answer (score 15):

Stack Exchange, Inc doesn't encourage one-on-one conversations with the moderators because they are busy enough already.

If there is an issue with someone who is answering questions, flag one of their questions and briefly explain the issue in the flag comment box.  It should be sufficient for 99% of the issues you're likely to have with another user.

The reality is that a lot of issues (such as suspected vote fraud, abuse, attacks, etc) can be dealt with simply by flagging their posts and explaining the issue.

If you feel that your issue must not only receive moderator attention, but that it would take a long time to explain and requires some amount of conversation to fully communicate the issue, then you're probably better off sending a message to team at stackoverflow per the contact link at the bottom of every page.

Comment: @SpencerRuport Sure, why not. I'll edit it momentarily.

Comment: @SpencerRuport I don't understand.  My two suggestions involve flagging (private) and email (private).  At what point do I suggest that you should air your, or someone elses, dirty laundry in an open forum? Perhaps if you explained why these two solutions will not help fix your problem, I might be able to suggest an alternative which fits your needs better.

Comment: I think Adam is saying that full on *chats* take up a lot of time, but if you can explain the issue in a flag then a moderator can follow up with it

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest [pinging them in chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#notifications) and asking them to create a private room with you.

Comment: Are fully private rooms still available? I thought they weren't

Comment: Any moderator and SE employee can enter a private room, but, you know, there's this thing called respect :)

Comment: @simchona - they're available for use by mods, with the understanding that they're meant to be used only when necessary: http://modnewsletter.stackexchange.com/2011/11/november-2011-newsletter/

Answer (score 2):

You can email team@stackoverflow.com

Or just click on the **contact us** link on the bottom of every page.

See [@Jeff's answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/49834/155556) for more information.

Comment: You should really go through mods first though, unless it's something you know they can't help with; there's no reason to escalate straight to employees for a simple question