# Why was this edit approved, then rejected?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

On [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123289/contributor-support), I made an edit when the OP added a comment into the question body:

> EDIT: I find it interesting that my question has a negative score. I hadn't realized that seeking private assistance has been deemed inappropriate by a clearly infallible community.

The [original edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/2654) was approved. Then, a few minutes later the original poster added the comment back in as a rollback. I made another suggested edit, but this time [it was rejected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/2655) with the following reason:

> This edit introduces spam, defaces the post in some way, or is otherwise inappropriate.

I was under the impression that comments that didn't help the question text were undesirable. What made my second edit spam?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cast a vote to reject that edit.

I did so because, while the edit *should have been a comment and not an edit on the post*, it was a point I wanted to address, and as such felt it needed to remain so that the comment I was about to leave would make sense.

If this had been Stack Overflow proper, then that edit would definitely have been correct. I felt that given this was *Meta* Stack Overflow, it was highly common to see such whining about downvotes in the question.

If my rejection was wrong, I should hope a moderator would re-do the edit and then [cause some harm to my appliances](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/conversation/rchern-strikes-back) / [leave my milk out](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/127139#127139)!

(Also, I apologize for rejecting your edit. I do understand you were trying to help. Please don't take it personally / let it prevent you from continuing to suggest edits!)

Comment: *it was a point I wanted to address, and as such felt it needed to remain so that the comment I was about to leave would make sense.* I feel like you may have rejected the edit for your own purposes, rather than that it really was spam. Your comment would have made sense, whether or not that was in the question.

Comment: It wasn't spam, I agree. I was not thrilled with the rejection reasons. maybe I should have chose "other". What I felt was the best reasoning under "vandalism" was "defaces the post in some way, or is otherwise inappropriate". Again, I apologize for confusion!

Comment: The thing is, you marked my edit as *spam* because you wanted to make a point. At the risk of sounding whiny, I think you rejected it for an invalid reason if this is your only reason.

Comment: I agree. You have a valid point. I apologize if you feel I rejected your edit for an invalid reason. I can't undo my vote. I call 'em as I see 'em and if I am wrong, I apologize.

Comment: Well, there's no use beating a dead horse. Thank you for explaining your rationale.

Comment: FWIW, @simchona - I can't change the rejection, but I have locked the post since it didn't seem to be going anywhere productive.

Comment: @shog understood. I saw that you edited it too which was my main aim