# Action to be taken when Abused and deleted question?

Tags: discussion, support, abuse, offensive

I am a regular user in Stack Overflow, I was answering questions as usual and I came accross a question where user linked a question and said he wants similar functionality, (linked question already had so many answers)

I said if you want similar functionality then try answers over there and I said that his question was too broad. For that he started abusing  and before I could flag his comment he deleted his question.

Now how can I report that to moderators?

Here is a snapshot
[image]

Comment: "How can I report moderator?" See [Option to contact moderator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/49833/260388)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply flag another post, paste the link to the now-deleted question and explain what happened. Moderators can see deleted posts and comments, so they should be able to handle it.

Please keep up with your efforts to make Stack Overflow better by linking and flagging to duplicates!

Comment: I do not have link of deleted question now

Comment: You have the link to the user profile of the user. Give a time it was posted as accurate as possible. They should be able to find it then.

Answer (score 7):

Typically you would flag another post of the user if they deleted to post in question.

If that is not possible as they have no more posts then you can always mod flag one of your own posts and explain what it going on.

If you have the link then include that in the flag.  If not then let them know when this was and if you remember the user, the user name as well.  Mods can see all deleted content so they should be able to find it and take action if needed.